# SSN Regular Expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm just starting to learn Regular Expressions.  My code works, but I'd like to make it better.

```
# Ensure all of the Social Security numbers use dashes for delimiters.
# Example: 480.01.4430 and 480014430 would both be 480-01-4430.
def format_ssns(string)
  string.gsub!(/\./, '-') if string =~ /(\d{9})|(\d{3})\D(\d{2})\D(\d{4})/
  string.insert(3, '-') if string =~ /(\d{9})/
  string.insert(6, '-') if string =~ /(\d{3})\D(\d{6})/
  p string
end

format_ssns("234601422, 350.80.0744, 013-60-8762")
```

Comment: This would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Your code works, but you want to improve it.

Comment: It is not a question. It is a statement telling what the OP like to do.

Answer (score 3):

This covers all 3:

```
string = "234601422, 350.80.0744, 013-60-8762"
string.gsub /\b(\d{3})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{4})\b/, '\1-\2-\3'
#=> "234-60-1422, 350-80-0744, 013-60-8762"
```

Answer (score 1):

how about `s.gsub!(/\D/, '').insert(3, '-').insert(6, '-')`

Comment: There's lots of problems with this one, but I'll start with this: `gsub!` returns nil if there's no match.

Comment: yes, thank you for point it out